# Negating a nested query returns empty result set

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a question about negated nested queries in Rails 6.1.3.1:

I have two models: `Profile` and `Task`, connected by the foreign key `Task#profile_id`.
My goal is to select profiles based on whether they contain tasks in a certain `state`.
For this, I use a nested query which returns the profile ids, and feed them to the main query, like so:

```rb
# Profiles containing any stopped task
Profile.where(
  id: Task.where(state: "stopped").select(:profile_id)
)
```

... which works nicely. However, when I try to negate the nested query with `not`:

```rb
# Profiles containing no started task
Profile.where.not(
  id: Task.where(state: "started").select(:profile_id)
)
```

... it does not work -- I always get an empty result set. (Of course the database contains entries for both the negated and the non-negated cases!)

Any help appreciated :)

(P.S. I'm aware that the nested queries are bad in terms of performance, but with the given data model I was not able to come up with anything better :-/ Also happy to hear suggestions about this!)

Comment: These are not exactly negations of one another. Right now the conditions are "Profile has any stopped tasks" or "Profile has ONLY not started (stopped?) tasks". You are certain that there are profiles that have no started tasks, as in every single task is stopped? As far as suggestions go this is a pure join so the subquery is not needed just add `has_many :tasks` to the `Profile` class. Then `Profile.joins(:tasks).where(tasks: {state: "stopped"}).distinct` would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just setup an assocation and join it instead.

Profiles with a least one stopped task

```
Profile.joins(:tasks)
       .where(tasks: { state: 'stopped' })
```

Profiles with no stopped tasks:

```
Profile.left_joins(:tasks)
       .where(tasks: { state: 'stopped', id: nil })
```

Profiles with `x` number of stopped tasks:

```
Profile.joins(:tasks)
       .group(:id)
       .where(tasks: { state: 'stopped'})
       .having(Task.arel_table[:id].count.eq(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

We ultimately ended up using `pluck` instead of `select` to get the ids. This is not an ideal solution in terms of performance/memory usage, but in our server environment nothing else would work (the suggestion by max *should* have worked but didn't -- probably a deeper lying issue in the setup).

Anyway, in case anybody ever runs in the same problem, here is *a* solution:

```rb
Profile.where.not(
  id: Task.where(state: "started").pluck(:profile_id)
)
```